# AngularJS how to build a custom input search box using regex or switch case

Tags: angularjs

angularJS how to build a custom input search box  using regex or switch case

how can u do a regex how u write the any example like i am calling names from this https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users how can i add a custom filter on the names

Comment: Hello Maven, Welcome to Stackoverflow. Sorry for my associates downvotes. Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people who write code because they love it. We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use filter pipes for repeat block, which will hide filtered results. A model from the input filed needs to be passed into it. You can create your own, custom filter too.

Here is a small demo:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  // $scope.resource = [{...}, ...] // pull out manually
  $http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users").then(function(res) {
    $scope.resource = res.data; // pull out with an HTTP GET request
  })
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    Search: <input type="text" ng-model="search" />
    <ol>
      <li ng-repeat="data in resource | filter: search">{{data.name}}</li>
    </ol>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

---

You can write a custom filter for regex parameters:

```
app.filter('regex', function() {
  return function(input, field, regex) {
    var patt = new RegExp(regex);
    var out = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
      if (patt.test(input[i][field]))
        out.push(input[i]);
    }
    return out;
  };
});
```

And use it as:

```
ng-repeat="name in names | regex:'type':'^c5$'"
```

Comment: @mavenjohnson Angular 1 is AngularJS (_with highest version of 1.7.2_)

Comment: @mavenjohnson I changed the code and added your resource with JSON file. I recommend you to learn the basics of AngularJS in some tutorial that you can find online.